# Mail object add inlineImages as BLOB

Tags: javascript

I use Google script (based on Javascript) to send Mail with [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app). I am calling the google script function from the Javascript of a web page with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) (that part work fine).

I succefully send a **mail object** to the Google function with something like this :

```
var mail = {
    to:"",
    cc:"",
    subject:"",
    htmlBody:""
}
google.script.run.sendMail(mail);
```

But now I want to add **inlineImages** to the mail by passing the image in BLOB format (load from the web page).

Image are add by a custom mail editor, I can easily add **cid** in the htmlBody and get the file by an *input type="file"*.

But **I don't see how to add the inlineImages parameter in my object like this :**

```
var mail = {
    to:"",
    cc:"",
    subject:"",
    htmlBody:"",
    inlineImages: 
    {
        imageCID1 : imageBLOB1,
        imageCID2 : imageBLOB2,
        ...
        imageCIDn : imageBLOBn
    }
}
google.script.run.sendMail(mail);
```

Comment: Personally for me it is unclear what is your problem. Could you please define it better? As I understand, you have an array of BLOBs selected by user and acquired through custom mail editor. You have working mail script. Why can't you just add them as properties to your `inlineImages`?

Comment: Damm, I just see *inlineImages : a JavaScript object containing a mapping from image key (String) to image data (BlobSource)* from google ressource, I don't know that much Javascript and I did not understand that it's was simply a map object. I will check on Javascript Map, but I think I can handle it.